# build python script to exe file using cx_freeze

Tags: python, user-interface, exe, cx-freeze

i am trying to convert my python script to a `exe` file
that anyone can run it from any computer, including computers with no python.
so i see some guides that explain the best way is to use in the `cx_freeze` library.
so i built a small gui application that use in tkinter only, this is my code:

```
import tkinter
top = tkinter.Tk()
# Code to add widgets will go here...
top.mainloop()
```

and this is my setup file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(
    name="GUI PROGRAM",
    version="0.1",
    description="MyEXE",
    executables=[Executable("try.py", base="Win32GUI")],
    )
```

and i run this command:

```
python setup.py build
```

and then i get this error:

```
KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY
```

and it only happens when i use tkinter. so i guess i miss something and i need to add in some way the tkinter to the setup file.
can someone help me?
thanks lot you guys.

Comment: what version of python are you using? I would suggest pyinstaller as a package to exe library... its very easy to use

Comment: i use in python 3.6, and i try them and they are really complicated

Comment: Not as difficult as Cx_Freeze I can ensure you.

Answer (score 0):

Try you altering your setup script to this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys
import os.path

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR,'tcl','tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

files = {"include_files": ["<Path to Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll", "<Path To Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tk86t.dll"], "packages": ["tkinter"]}

setup(
    name="GUI PROGRAM",
    version="0.1",
    description="MyEXE",
    options = {"build_exe": files},
    executables=[Executable("try.py", base="Win32GUI")],
)
```

`os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR,'tcl','tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')` will remove the error message, while `files = {"include_files": ["<Path to Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll", "<Path To Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tk86t.dll"], "packages": ["tkinter"]}` will include the missing Tk and Tcl runtimes.

Comment: @Mark green  This is my updated answer if you have not seen it.